# if ignore happened return something else?

Tags: java, jsoup

```
package utils;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Urlpicture {

    public String get_main_url(int num) {
        String jpgurl = null;
    try{
        String url = "https://www.zigbang.com/items1/"+num; 
        jpgurl = "http://z1.zigbang.com/items/7697786/538ec7a16033f0c32eac29ac50deb04a1e6bf3ba.jpg?h=800&q=60";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();    // this part require try catch
        jpgurl = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg?h=800&q=60]").get(0).absUrl("src");



        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println(jpgurl);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jpgurl;




    }


}
```

Getting Document from Jsoup Connect. 
But If Jsoup.connect give an error. I want to 
jgurl as something else and keep running the code.
is it impossible?
(this code will called multiple time from outside but if one exception occured. it stopped)

outside source calling this urlpicture

```
    @RequestMapping("/search")
    public ModelAndView searchHandler() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("t_search");

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> mlist = rd.test_room();


//=====================================================  
        List<String> urlcol = new ArrayList<>();
          JSONArray json_arr=new JSONArray();// 
            for (Map<String, Object> map : mlist) {
                JSONObject json_obj=new JSONObject();
                String url = null;
                System.out.println(map.get("SELL_NUM"));
                int num = Integer.parseInt(map.get("SELL_NUM")+"");
                String str = (urp.get_main_url(num).toString());// this calling the function
                System.out.println(str);
       }
                   urlcol.add(url);
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();

                    Object value = entry.getValue();


                    try {

                        json_obj.put(key,value);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                           
                }
                (json_arr).put(json_obj);

           }
```

===========================================================after fix

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
    public ModelAndView searchHandler() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("t_search");

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> mlist = rd.test_room();



        List<String> urlcol = new ArrayList<>();
          JSONArray json_arr=new JSONArray();
            for (Map<String, Object> map : mlist) {
                JSONObject json_obj=new JSONObject();
                String url = null;
                String input = null;
                System.out.println(map.get("SELL_NUM"));
                int num = 0;
                num = Integer.parseInt(map.get("SELL_NUM")+"");
                input = "https://www.zigbang.com/items1/"+num; 
                System.out.println(input);

              try{
                url= (urp.get_main_url(input));
                System.out.println(url);

              }catch(Exception e){
                  System.out.println("No=");
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  url = "http://z1.zigbang.com/items/7697786/538ec7a16033f0c32eac29ac50deb04a1e6bf3ba.jpg?h=800&q=60";
```

## }

```
@Service
public class Urlpicture {

    public String get_main_url(String url) {
        Document doc;
        String jpgurl = null;
    try{

        jpgurl = "http://z1.zigbang.com/items/7697786/538ec7a16033f0c32eac29ac50deb04a1e6bf3ba.jpg?h=800&q=60";
        jpgurl = Jsoup.connect(url).get().select("img[src$=.jpg?h=800&q=60]").get(0).absUrl("src"); 


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }finally{

        return jpgurl;
    }
```

=====================================================================
after fix it keep running after exception. 
but even though the url link is exist with valid number 
it return all value as exception.

```
7666495
https://www.zigbang.com/items1/7666495// this link is valid but throw exception
No=
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.main_controller.searchHandler(main_controller.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springf
```

I have no idea why this keep throwing the exception for all values

Comment: Move declaration of jgurl from try section, otherwise its scope is limited only to it and it can't be accessed in catch. You can declare it before try, give it default value (error message) and if try section will be executed without problems it will also update jgurl to proper value.

Comment: I changed my code.

Comment: @manjoojo do not change your code if it changes your question

Comment: @manjoojo: can you add that 'outside' (the caller) code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the scope of your `jgurl` variable, which you need to declare before the `try` block as shown below.

Also, to solve the second issue, you need to extract the downloading image logic to a separate method and call it again with the default `num` when the image is not found for the given `num`, which is also shown below:

```
public String get_main_url(int num) {
        int num = 7453201;
        String jpgurl  = null;
        try {
            downloadImage(num);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            num=0;//set the default value for which img exists
            downloadImage(num);//call downloadImage with default num
        }
    }

private String downloadImage(int num) {
     String url = "https://www.zigbang.com/items1/"+num; 
     System.out.println(url);
     Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
     jpgurl = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg?h=800&q=60]").get(0).absUrl("src");
     System.out.println(i + "="+jpgurl);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue now, can you explain it?

Comment: ok so this get_main_url() function called from outside. I'm entering the multiple number and getting jpg from certain web-cite

Comment: can you add that 'outside' (the caller) code as well?

Comment: but if wrong number entered.   Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();   part throwing null point exception.

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();   this JSOUP part required try catch

Comment: if exception occured I want to set jpgurl with something available value

Comment: when jsoup throw exception It's over

Comment: Why you want to download 3 times the same image?

Comment: i changed my main code. just added forloop for explain purpose

Comment: okay, updated my code above, just take out the `downloadImage` logic to a separate method and upon exception, set the default `num` value accordingly & call `downloadImage` again

Comment: try{
          url= (urp.get_main_url(num).toString());
          
        }catch(Exception e){
         url = "http://z1.zigbang.com/items/7697786/538ec7a16033f0c32eac29ac50deb04a1e6bf3ba.jpg?h=800&q=60";
        }
          System.out.println(url);

Comment: sir can you look my code again? after I fix it. it does not stop after one exception. but problem is that it gives all values as exception even though the url link is valid.